# Prevent multiple connection from the same username

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using the provided ASP.NET SQL Membership & Role providers in my application.

How can I prevent that the same user does login from different workstations using the same credentials? I can imagine to use the IP address for this but I dont really know where to start from...

Also what about users behind the same router? Is there a way to prevent them access from different client PC's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP would not be a very good way as all users behind a typical company LAN would appear to you as connecting from the same IP. A workaround is to logout the user that is logged in with the same credential thus keeping only the latest one logged on. This can be achieved by keeping the logged in user's ID or name in Application or DB. As soon as a new user session is started, check if the user is present in Application/DB. If so, mark it dirty. In the pages, check the presence of UserID/Name in the Application and if the user is marked as dirty, invoke a logout. This can be implemented in a BasePage that all the pages within the site/app inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can store whatever you are using to uniquely identify the user like a UserId in [ApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) and check to see if that value is not null.  You add their UserId value to ApplicationState at the start of SessionState and then at the end of SessionState remove that value from ApplicationState.

ApplicationState is global to the web application meaning it is accesible to all users and sessions while SessionState is limited in scope to a single user and session.